# Can a KML Document use a URI as an ID?

Tags: kml

[Google's KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#document) only states that a `Document`'s ID attribute must be unique.  Are there any other restrictions on the content used as an ID? Specifically, is there any reason a URI would be an invalid document identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some investigation, Google Earth appears to accept URIs as valid Document IDs.  My guess is that it's doing a simple text comparison, since it has no reason to expect that the ID has a special format.